# Laravel/SES sporadically not sending emails?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-5, amazon-ses

Sorry about the vague title, I only have very vague information and have no idea where to get any more.

Some of the users of our app have reported they're not receiving emails now and again. We're using SES with Laravel to send them, when I went to test, they weren't sending for about half an hour, and then suddenly were sending correctly again.

Here's what we know:

- All items in the queue were processed without issue
- There's nothing at all in my error logs
- Nothing of note in my SES console
- Emails were definitely not sending
- I changed nothing, and they suddenly are again

I understand that's probably way too vague for a meaningful answer, but does anyone know where/how I'd debug this? I can't find any record of any failed/successful sends.

Comment: What evidence do you have that the app was not sending email for half hour?

Comment: Try debugging with Laravel Telescope